# CriteriaBuilder - Join table to itself with complex ON

Tags: java, jpa

I have a table called `programs` and I want to create a query using `CriteriaBuilder` that joins the table to itself as in:

```
SELECT *
FROM programs p1
LEFT JOIN programs p2 
    ON p1.name = p2.name AND p1.version < p2.version
```

So far I have

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Program> cq = cb.createQuery(Program.class);
Root<Program> root = cq.from(Program.class);
Join<Program, Program> programJoin = root.join("name", JoinType.LEFT);
programJoin.on(cb.equal(//I don't know...))
```

But I'm stuck here, not knowing how to recreate the above SQL `ON` condition `p1.version < p2.version`

Comment: The duplicate in question does not answer my question, as it does not deal with a scenario in which both tables are of the same type

Comment: Did you try the answer of the other question? What error do you get?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible using criteria builder because criteria builder works with your entities model. You would need to have the association to another Program declared in your Program class. Your `root.join("name", JoinType.LEFT)` won't work neither because it expects the "name" to be property of type Program but it is String. If you used type-safe metamodel (instead of String names of properties) you would get compiler error.